# simple compass direction of a custom geo-location

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, geolocation, compass-geolocation

A simple compass that points towards the direction of a custom geo-location that you can specify by providing latitude and longitude of the location.
i try but there are mistakes 
I do not know where this error

class ViewController: UIViewController ,CLLocationManagerDelegate{
var locationmanager:CLLocationManager!

```
@IBOutlet var arrowImageView: UIImageView!

var currentHeading = CLHeading()

var userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
var destLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

var latitudeOfTargetedPoint = 48.858093
var longitudeOfTargetedPoint = 2.294694

var angle:Float!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   locationmanager = CLLocationManager()
    locationmanager.delegate = self
    locationmanager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationmanager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationmanager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationmanager.distanceFilter = 100.0
    locationmanager.startUpdatingHeading()
}

func showUserAndDestinationOnMap()
{
    // Calculate the rectangle that contains the current position and the destination
    var maxLat:Double = fmax(userLocation.latitude,  latitudeOfTargetedPoint)
    var maxLon:Double = fmax(userLocation.longitude, longitudeOfTargetedPoint)

    var minLat:Double = fmin(userLocation.latitude,  latitudeOfTargetedPoint)
    var minLon:Double = fmin(userLocation.longitude, longitudeOfTargetedPoint)

    // Calculate the latitude, longitude width when displaying map
    var mapMargin:Double = 1.5;  // Width route enters (1.0) + margin (0.5)
    var leastCoordSpan:Double = 0.005;    // Enlarge maximum value when the display
    var span_x:Double = fmax(leastCoordSpan, fabs(maxLat - minLat) * mapMargin);
    var span_y:Double = fmax(leastCoordSpan, fabs(maxLon - minLon) * mapMargin);

    var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(span_x, span_y);

    // Calculate the center of the destination your location
    var center:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((maxLat + minLat) / 2, (maxLon + minLon) / 2);
    var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);




       }


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {

    self.showUserAndDestinationOnMap()


}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println(error)
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading!) {

    var degrees = newHeading.magneticHeading

    if (degrees > 180)
    {
        degrees = 360 - degrees;
    }
    else
    {
        degrees = 0 - degrees;
    }

    //    Rotate the arrow image
    if self.arrowImageView != nil {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: { self.arrowImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.arrowImageView.transform,self.DegreesToRadians(degrees) )  })

    }

}
```

func DegreesToRadians (value: Double) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(value * M_PI / 180.0)
    }

func RadiansToDegrees (value: Double) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(value * 180.0 / M_PI)}

if any one can do this

and sorry about my english :P~

Comment: What are the errors/messages?  Which lines?

Comment: There are no error the project is work but the problem is in the arrow if  i run app the arrow image is spin fast i want the arrow compass points towards the direction  if you don't understand download the project here  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n0sak8tw08cnpwe/compass2.zip?dl=0)

Comment: @Paulw11 check  the link